# CGI script to set a cookie and reload

Tags: perl, cgi

I have a CGI script that gets some parameters in the URL, and presents a form.
when the user submits the form, the information in the form is saved in a cookie.
Now, on the press of the submit, I want the same URL to be called, including the parameters it was originally called with.

Example: maybe be clearer:
Someone calls me like this:

**www.mysite.com/script.cgi?name=nec&mail=necnec**

On this page, user can choose color (red, yellow, green).
When pressing button submit, I want my page to be called like:

***www.mysite.com/script.cgi?name=nec&mail=necnec***&color=green

How I do this?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your script named **script.cgi** might look like below.

### script.cgi

```
#!C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe
use strict;
use warnings;  
use CGI;  
my $query = new CGI;  
my $p_name=$query->param('name')|| "NO Name";  
my $p_mail=$query->param('mail')|| "NO Email";  
print $query->header( "text/html" );  
print <<START_HERE;  
       <html>  
       <head>  
           <title>Your First CGI Script</title>  
       </head>  
       <body>  
           <h1>This is a script Web page</h1>  
           <p>  
              <form name='testform' method='get' action='test.pl'>  
              <input type="hidden" name="name" value=$p_name />  
              <input type="hidden" name="mail" value=$p_mail /> 
              <select name='color'>  
                      <option value="red">Red</option>  
                      <option value="green">Green</option>  
                      <option value="white">White</option>  
                      <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>  
               </select>  
               <input type='submit' value='submit' name="submit" />  
               </form>  
            </p>  
          </body>  
          </html>  
          START_HERE 
    #must have a line after "START_HERE" or Perl won't recognize  
    #the token
```

Using param method **script.cgi** will take parameters **name** and **mail** and
after form submit,this page will take you to **test.pl**. Here **color**, **name** and **mail** parameters are available.Because name and mail are sent using hidden fields.

### test.pl

```
#!C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe
use strict;  
use warnings;  
use CGI;  
my $query = new CGI;  
my $cookie_color=$query->cookie('color');
my $name=$query->param('name')|| "NO Name";  
my $mail=$query->param('mail')|| "NO Email";  
my $color=$query->param('color')|| $cookie_color || "NO color";
my $cookie = $query->cookie(-name=>'color',
    -value=>$color_value,
    -expires=>'+4h',
    -path=>'/');
print $query->header( "text/html" );  
print $query->header(-cookie=>$cookie);
print <<START_HERE;  
         <html>  
           <head>  
              <title>Script to check the Parameters</title>  
           </head>  
           <body>  
              <h1>This is a test Web page</h1>  
              <p>Name: $name</p>  
              <p>Mail: $mail</p>  
              <p>Color: $color</p>  
           </body>  
        </html>  
       START_HERE   
#must have a line after "START_HERE" or Perl won't recognize  
#the token
```

You can also use **action='script.cgi'** in **testform**. And Display **name**, **mail** ,**color**  similar to **test.pl** in **script.cgi**.

Cookie can be set in **test.pl**. That is after submitting form.